# How to search in the Element panel?

Tags: html, user-interface, google-chrome-devtools

I want to search for a class, but I want the result to display in the Element panel, not the Source panel, so that I can see the element is highlighted the web. However, it seems that I can only search in Source? Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to search elements by their class names by selecting an element in the element tab and then pressing Ctrl+F. In Chrome.

As far as I can tell you have to open it every time you use the devtools. I don't see an option to have it present permanently.

[image]